# jQuery Supersize play button and tray down button not showing up II

Tags: jquery, supersized

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it, but I need to extend the original question
"jQuery Supersize play button and tray down button not showing up", answered by mr. mccannf.
I have the exact same problem, but after replacing that 'image_path' line, nothing changed.
Since it seems to be the solution for the question, I would like to understand what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ops. I was editing supersized.shutter.js and calling supersized.shutter.min.js. That's all. Sorry for the trouble.